# Angular forEach add values into each objects

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I dont know how to do this :

I've an array of objects :

```
$scope.eventSources = [
      {title: 'Equipe 1 vs equipe 2',start: new Date(y, m, 1),color: 'black'},
      {title: 'Equipe 2 vs equipe 3',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),color: 'black'},
];
```

How do I add

```
className: 'evenement'
```

Inside each objects ?

I've tried this :

```
angular.forEach($scope.eventSources,function(value,index){
                value.className = 'evenement';
            });
```

but it doesnt work, because className doesn't exist yet.

Thank you

Comment: `but it doesnt work, because className doesn't exist yet.` - makes no sense actually. If `value` is an object, you can easily assign a new property to it. And by the code shown in the OP, it's definitely an object. Can you create a short example showing the real problem you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

access the array object using the index

```
angular.forEach($scope.eventSources,function(value,index){
  $scope.eventSources[index]["className"] = "evenement";
});
```

Or you can add that to the value also

```
angular.forEach($scope.eventSources,function(value,index){
  value.className = "evenement";
});
```

Comment: `value` is the object, we can just add a property to that

Comment: @Frank Modica you are right. but that does not mean the above scenario is wrong. there are so many ways to do this, i include your one also

Comment: I know, I am not the one who downvoted you. But your original way is still more complicated than it needs to be, given that we're using `angular.forEach`. I see you have updated with the simpler solution.

Answer (score -1):

Map through your array then assign property for each item.

```
 var newArray = $scope.eventSources.map(function(item) {
    item.className: 'evenement';

   return item;
});

 console.log(newArray); 
 // result
 [
  {title: 'Equipe 1 vs equipe 2',start: new Date(y, m, 1),color: 'black',  
  className:'evenement'},
  {title: 'Equipe 2 vs equipe 3',start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),color: 'black', className:'evenement'},
 ];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of just the `obj` argument in `angular.forEach` since you need to assign a new property `className` to each object(for ex : `itm`) as `itm.className = 'evenement';`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.eventSources = [{
      title: 'Equipe 1 vs equipe 2',
      start: new Date(),
      color: 'black'
    },
    {
      title: 'Equipe 2 vs equipe 3',
      start: new Date(),
      end: new Date(),
      color: 'black'
    }
  ];

  angular.forEach($scope.eventSources, function(itm) {
    itm.className = 'evenement';
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <pre>{{eventSources | json}}</pre>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually, `angular.forEach` takes three arguments `(obj, iterator, [context])` and the iterator (which you intended to refer to) also takes three arguments: `(value, key, obj)`, where value is the value of an object property or an array element, key is the object property key or array element index and obj is the object/array itself.

Comment: @ippi, tell me about it. That's exactly what the documentation says. OP here just needs the `obj` in the `iterator` to add a new property, rest all arguments are irrelevant.

Comment: @Sajal It doesn't hurt to have a good answer AND to be technically correct. Sorry if I sounded snarky. I still think you should edit it.

Comment: I do agree on using the correct vocabulary but i guess the phrasing here was a little off. Anyhow, I updated the answer with a better phrase for anyone who reads it in the future.